# In bash, how do I expand a wildcard while it's inside double quotes?

Tags: bash, wildcard, space

I would like to write the following function in bash:

```
go() {
  cd "~/project/entry ${1}*"
}
```

What this would do is to cd into a project subdirectory with prefix `entry` (note space) and possibly a long suffix. I would only need to give it a partial name and it will complete the suffix of the directory name.

So, if for example, I have the following folders:

```
~/project/entry alpha some longer folder name
~/project/entry beta another folder name
~/project/entry gamma
```

I can run `go b` and it will put me into `~/project/entry beta another folder name`.

The problem is, of course, that the wildcard doesn't expand inside double quotes. I cannot omit the quotes because then I will not be able to capture the spaces properly.

How do I get the wildcard to expand while at the same time preserving the spaces?

Comment: Quoting rules are applied character-by-character -- there's no reason for an entire word to be quoted the same way. One can, for instance, `'do something'"like $this"'to mix quoting styles'`.

Comment: See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Move the quotes. Just don't quote the `*`. Probably also good not to quote the `~`.

```
go() {
  cd ~/"project/entry ${1}"*
}
```

That being said if this matches more than one thing `cd` will use the first match and ignore all the other matches.

Comment: "Probably also good" is an understatement; you also mustn't quote the tilde when you want it to refer to your home directory.